# How to implement required File upload attribute, on Update action, in Yii 2?

Tags: validation, file-upload, yii2, modelform, filehelpers

I need file upload field to be required for both Create and Update actions, and the required validation and validation of types to be performed in both cases.

This is how my form looks like (Note: It's a form, not an Active Record model):

```
<?php

namespace app\models;

use Yii;
use yii\base\Model;
use yii\base\Object;
use yii\helpers\FileHelper;

class MyCustomForm extends Model
{

    public $file_image;

    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            [
                [['file_image'], 'file', 'skipOnEmpty' => false, 'extensions' => 'jpg, jpeg, png, bmp, jpe']
            ]
        ];
    }

    public function scenarios()
    {
        $scenarios = parent::scenarios();
        //Scenarios Attributes that will be validated
        $scenarios['action_add'] = ['file_image'];
        $scenarios['action_edit'] = ['file_image'];
        return $scenarios;
    }
}
```

And this is how my controller actions looks like.

The Create action works as expected (on POST request I'm taking the Uploaded File with UploadedFile::getInstance command)

```
public function actionCreate()
{
    $model_form = new MyCustomForm(['scenario' => 'action_add']);
    if (Yii::$app->request->isPost && $model_form->load(Yii::$app->request->post())) {
        $model_form->file_image = \yii\web\UploadedFile::getInstance($model_form, "file_image");
        if($model_form->validate()) {
            if(isset($model_form->file_image)){
                //I'm uploading my image to some cloud server here

                //creating corresponding $model_entity for database, fill with the data from the form and save it
                $model_entity->save();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But I'm facing with an issue when doing the same on Update action. In database I have the URL of image that is on third party cloud server and I can access it and display the image in my form (so GET request on Update works, I'm getting the corresponding entity from database and fill the form with data). But for POST, file validation is failing, if I don't have file assigned in the model and the POST request for Update is not working.

```
public function actionUpdate($id)
{
    $model_entity = $this->findModel($id);        

    $image_URL = //I'm having URL to corresponding image here;

    $model_form = new MyCustomForm(['scenario' => 'action_edit']);        
    $model_form_data = [$model_form->formName() => $model_entity->attributes];
    $model_form->load($model_form_data); 

    if (Yii::$app->request->isPost && $model_form->load(Yii::$app->request->post())) {
        //if we upload image again this will work
        //NOTE: I have another text fields in the form and If I only change them
        //and if I don't change the file image, the following result will return NULL and validation will fail
        $file_uploaded_image = \yii\web\UploadedFile::getInstance($model_form, "file_image");

        if(isset($file_uploaded_image)){
            //new image is uploaded on update, this scenario will be OK
        } else {
            //no image is uploaded on update, this scenario will fail
        }

       if($model_form->validate()) {
           //this will fail if I don't upload image on Update
       }

    }

}
```

I have tried many things in Update action, before validation, in order to find a workaround to get the image and validation to not fail. For example:

```
$dataImg = file_get_contents($image_URL);
$model_form->file_image = $dataImg;
```

or trying to do get with temporary file:

```
$dataImg = file_get_contents($dataImg);
$filePath = \yii\helpers\FileHelper::createDirectory("/images/tmp/test.png", 777);
file_put_contents($filePath, $dataImg);
$model_form->file_image = $filePath;
```

But none of them is working. Is there any solution to this scenario?
Note that I will have to use a Froms (as above) and not the ActiveRecord, since my real project is more complex that example listed.

Answer (score 1):

Write this code in your **Model(MyCustomForm)** :

```
class MyCustomForm extends Model
{

    public $file_image;

    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            [['file_image',],'required','on'=>['create','update']],
            [['file_image'], 'file','extensions' => 'jpg, jpeg, png, bmp, jpe'],
        ];
    }
}
```

Write this code in your **actionCreate**() :

```
$model_form = new MyCustomForm();
$model_form->scenario = "create";
```

Write this code in your **actionUpdate**() :

```
$model_form = new MyCustomForm();
$model_form->scenario = "update";
```

Or you can add **scenario** by this :

```
$model_form = new MyCustomForm(['scenario' => 'create']);
```

I have tried this and it is working.